# Not able to move file in folder in PHP

Tags: php

Issue is, if I move image on local server it's working but not working on live server

Here is the code :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../admin/content/";
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $val) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $_REQUEST["no"] . "_" . $path['filename'];
    $ext = $path['extension'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],  $target_dir . $filename . "." . $ext);
}
```

Target directory path is also correct.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Chances are your PHP process does not have permission to write to the target directory

Comment: Please use `chmod` using give permisson.

Comment: Check where directory has permission or not. Use this command to give permission :  `sudo chmod -R 777 /Media_directory_Name`

Comment: There is minor issue in target directory path 

Correct one is : $target_dir = "../../admin/content/";

Answer (score 0):

Just give access permission to folder you wanna to move file in by this command

chmod [permissions] [file]

Ex: sudo chmod 755 content

Answer (score -1):

Try this code and check the error. Mostly it would be the access permission issue on the folder.

```
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],  $target_dir . $filename . "." . $ext);


if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
}
```